# Undefined variable apesar de ela estar definida

Tags: php, facebook-sdk

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oi</title>
</head>
 <body>
<?php 
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '58xxxx',
  'app_secret' => '04xxxxxxxxxxx879c7dx9cbbc',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);
$token =  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

//vars
$iatual = 0;
$inovo = 9;
$target_file = "uploads/img.jpg";
$texto = "TEXT TEXT TEXT..";
if (!empty($_POST['inputs'])) 
{
   $iatual = $_POST['inputs'];
   $inovo = $iatual + 10;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$idgrupos;


function LerArquivo($arquivo='arquivo.txt')
{
    $handlee = fopen($arquivo, 'r');
    $conteudo = fread($handlee, filesize($arquivo));
    fclose($handlee);
    $idgrupos = explode(',', $conteudo);
        return $idgrupos;
}   

echo $inovo.'<br>';
echo $iatual.'<br>';
function FazerPostagem($idgrupos)
{

  for ($i=$iatual; $i < count($idgrupos); $i++) { // LINHA 52


    try {


         // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
          $response = $fb->post('/'.$idgrupos[$i].'/photos', $data, $token); //LINHA 59
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();

          exit;
        } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
         echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }finally {
          $iatual = $i;
        }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
   echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'].'<br/>';

   if ($iatual == $inovo) {
    break 2;
   }

    echo $idgrupos[$i].'<br/>';
    echo $iatual.'<br/>';
  }
}
FazerPostagem(LerArquivo());

?>

<form action="phh.php" method="post">
<input type=text name="inputs"/><input type="submit">
</form> 
</body>
</head>
```

Erros:

> Notice: Undefined variable: iatual in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev\phh.php on line 51
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: fb in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev\phh.php on line 58
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0-dev\phh.php on line 58

Onde esta o erro? porque pelo que eu sei os escopos das minhas variaveis estao corretas

**EDIT:** Consegui fazer o código funcionar fazendo umas edições nele (não mudo aqui porque editei de uma forma que invalida a pergunta) pra quem quiser ver fiz assim: http://pastebin.com/8R2MX2UT Obrigado @juniorb2ss
Mas agora recebo o erro: Graph returned an error: Permissions error
Ao que aparenta, quando faço 10 posts o Graph API bloqueia e não deixa mais eu fazer. Alguem sabe como corrijo isso? Gastei mto tempo nisso é não quero desistir agora rsrs

Comment: A variável esta definida fora do escopo da função. É preciso definir ela dentro do escopo da função. Funções não tem acesso a variavel externas a menos que seja passada como parâmetro ou definida globalmente.

Comment: Coloque os erros como texto.

Comment: Fiz umas alterações e recebo esse erro..Alguem sabe como corrigir?

Comment: Se você tem uma nova pergunta, por favor utilize o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). A área que você usou para postar a pergunta é somente para respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variável está fora do escopo da função, por isso é disparado o erro.

Dois meios fáceis de resolver:

**1. Invocando global**

Nesse trecho:

```
function FazerPostagem($idgrupos)
{
```

Adicione uma chamada para `global`

```
function FazerPostagem($idgrupos)
{
    global $iatual, $fb;
```

**2. Passando por parâmetro**

```
function FazerPostagem($idgrupos, $iatual, $fb)
{
```

Lá na parte de baixo, onde invoca a função `FazerPostagem()`, ficaria assim:

```
FazerPostagem(LerArquivo(), $iatual, $fb);
```