# PHP - Como fazer para que caso não seja inserido dados um um POST, não apareça "Notice: Undefined index"

Tags: php

> É possível fazer com que se eu não inserir dados em um formulário com `method="get"`, quando for pra página do `action="/minha-url.php"`, caso não tenha inserido dados no formulário anterior, simplesmente não será exibido nada, ao invés de "Notice: Undefined index", etc...

Parte em que faço aparecer o conteúdo do GET:

```
<?php echo  ($_GET["email"]) ; ?>
```

> Quando eu insiro o e-mail, fica: **exemplo@exemplo.com**
>
> Quando eu não insiro, fica: **Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\teste.php on line 104**

---

**É uma pergunta bem simples, porém não obtive soluções, não achei nada na internet que resolvesse esse problema.**

Comment: esse é um dos assuntos mais recorrentes.. tem certeza de que procurou na internet?   http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87988/4793

Comment: Use `isset($_GET)` ou `isset($_GET["email"])`. Do tipo: `<?= isset($_GET["email"]) ? $_GET["email"] : ''>`;

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89960/4793

Answer (score 2):

Poderia usar o comando [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) para testar se o valor foi informado.

Desta forma:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["email"])){
    echo  ($_GET["email"]) ; 
}
?>
```

Observação: Você perceberá que muita gente utiliza a arroba ("@") para omitir erros, porém pode gerar uma grande dor de cabeça em uma situação em que você precise encontrar os erros e os mesmos não aparecem porque estão omitidos. Seria desta forma:

```
<?php 
echo  @($_GET["email"]); 
?>
```

Leia mais sobre a utilização ou não utilização da arroba ("@") em: [**Por que dizem que utilizar @ arroba pra suprimir erros é uma má prática?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/31016)

Answer (score 1):

existem meios para evitar o aparecimento desta mensagem de erro, mas, não sei ao certo o foco da sua aplicação que está desenvolvendo, uma boa prática é a validação da entrada de dados, que pode ser feita tanto em `HTML`, `JS` ou `PHP`, como você está realizando uma simples submissão utilizando o atributo `action`, recomendo que já valide pelo `HTML`, assim:

```
<form method="post" action="" >
    <input type="email" name="email" required />
</form>
```

Uma coisa a mais que reparei é que pela sua descrição você está enviando dados com o método `POST` e está usando a supervariável `$_GET[]`, o que é errado, o certo é se método `GET` logo `$_GET[]`, ou se método `POST` logo `$_POST[]` .

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), ela recebe uma constante `INPUT_GET` ou `INPUT_POST`:

```
<?php
echo filter_input(FILTER_POST, 'email');
```

essa função também permite aplicar filtros na variável lida, veja mais informações em [*Types of filter*](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) (página da documentação sem tradução)